# How to configure a custom domain for a containerized web app?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-service

I'd like to consider this Azure feature:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxXs9_ggBfg

But it won't be of much use to me if I'm unable to configure a custom domain for it. I'm having no problem with custom domains for standard App Service websites, but this is for containers.

I've tried searching for documentation, but I'm coming up empty.

**--EDIT--**

The technology I'm interested in is **Web Apps for Containers**; thanks to @sam-cogan for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the video is talking about Azure Web Apps for Containers (I would really recommend not asking people to watch a 30-minute video to understand your question). Assuming that is the case, then adding a custom domain name is the same as setting one up for a normal app service, you can do so through the custom domain name settings in the portal. The process is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

If you're looking to use a different service in Azure for hosting containers then please state which one and I will update. All of these can have custom domain names.

Comment: `"I would really recommend ..."` Thanks for pointing that out. Not sure what I was thinking there (I've edited). `"... adding a custom domain name is the same as setting one up for a normal app service ..."` OK, that's a good start. Didn't realize that But... doesn't the container get a new IP each time it starts?

Comment: If your looking at Web apps for containers, then no you don't get a new IP. The web app is wrapping to the container and deals with that for you. If you use Container Instances then that is a different story, you will get a new IP each time you launch. That said, for both web apps and ACI, you can just point your domain name at the default domain given to you by Azure using a CNAME

Answer (score 1):

Azure Container Instances usually provide a public IP address, so pointing a domain name to it should not be a problem.

You could map either an A record or a CNAME to your instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between configuring custom domain for normal web apps and web for container. I have tried below document and it is worked well. 
http://www.ayushrathi.com/configuring-a-custom-domain-name-for-web-app-azure-portal/

Comment: Looks good, thanks. But doesn't the container get a new IP each time it starts?

Comment: @InteXX NO. I have tested :)

Comment: Good, I believe you  :-)